# jQuery UI causes "uncaught" errors

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I want to use jQuery UI on my site. I downloaded custom build, but it didn't work. So I used "full" version from their site. It doesn't work either.

My only code is:

```
$('#gameRelease').datepicker();
```

And what I get is an error in console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fadeIn' of undefined
```

What can I do?

-- edit --

Okay, this is getting quite weird.

- I **have included** jQuery before jQuery UI.
- I have other things using jQuery before my code and they are working well.
- I tried disabling other plugins and commenting my previous code - nothing works.

Here's my full code (I cutted what's not important):

**JS**

```
(function($){})(window.jQuery);
$(document).ready(function() {
    /* jQuery UI */
    $('#gameRelease').datepicker();
})
```

**HTML**

```
<script src="/js/modernizr-1.7.min.js"></script>

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/jquery-ui-1.9.1.custom.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/script.js"></script>
```

Comment: Were you able to figure this out? If not, could you set up a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Silly problem. It turns out, that you have to load jQueryUI right after jQuery. And I loaded it later.

Answer (score 0):

The plugin *Nivo Slider for WordPress* (0.2) loads it's own `jquery.effects.core.js` file, which also makes the datepicker throw the same error.

If disabling the plugin makes the datepickers work, then you have to edit the `nivoslider4wp-show.php` file. Find the line with `<script ... src=".../js/jquery.effects.core.js" ...`, and comment it out using HTML comments (`<!-- ... -->`).